# R/data.table: read multiline script with fread

Tags: r, shell, data.table

I'm using `data.table::fread` to read input from a shell script. For readability I want to split the script on multiple lines using the line continuation character '\'.

However, `fread` doesn't seem to like shell scripts on multiple lines.

Examples:

```
library(data.table)
fread("cat test1.txt test2.txt") ## OK
```

Now split script on two lines:

```
fread("cat test1.txt \
           test2.txt")
Error in fread("cat test.txt \n           test.txt") : 
  Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 when detecting types (   first):            test.txt

## Same problem
fread("cat test.txt \\
           test.txt")
```

Is there any escape sequence or switch I'm missing?

If not, these are possible solutions I guess: 1) Don't split script at all 2) write script to a file and call that file with fread.

These are my settings:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3  chron_2.3-46 tcltk_3.2.3
```

Comment: By including a newline, you're triggering `fread` to believe your input is a csv, not a command line script. If you're trying to save on whitespace, use R itself, not the command line, to do so, e.g., `fread(paste0('cat test.txt', 'test.txt'))`

Comment: @MichaelChirico seems worth to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

embedding within `paste` is an alternative:

```
fread(paste("cat test1.txt",
           "test2.txt"))
```

If you are looking for an easy way to read multiple text files, you could either use

```
fread("cat t*.txt")
```

or if the .txt files don't follow the above example pattern of file names, perhaps move them to a sub-directory (say 'data') and read them all as below:

```
fread("ls data | cat")
```